# What is the reason for the sudden IoTConsensus startup error of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: consensus, apache-iotdb, iotdb

```
ERROR·o.a.i.db.service.DataNode:181-·Failto:start·server

org.apache.iotdb.commons.exception.StartupException: 
org.apache. iotdb.commons .exception.StartupException:Failed·to:start，IoTConsensus Servicel,because:IoTDB: 
failed to start IoTConsensus Service, 
"becauseCouldnotcreateServerSocketonaddress /192.168.5.29:40010.]
```

When starting up Apache `IoTDB` this morning, an error below popped out suddenly.

`IoTDB` was all executed normally before.

What may be the reason for this error? What may be temporarily wrong with this address on `IoTConsensus`?

```
ERROR o.a.i.db.service.DataNode:181 - [Fail to start server

org.apache.iotdb.commons.exception.StartupException: Failed to start [IoTConsensus Service], because could not createServerSocketonaddress: /192.2. 40010.]
```

[image: Picture of some textual output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if this port (socket) is occupied by another process in Apache IoTDB? Seems like this error information reflected that this address is already carrying other processes, and there is nothing wrong with IoTConsensus process itself.